# What is "to use a 4 square" in context of someone selling something?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/personalfinance/comments/1knnhr/im_buying_a_car_from_a_dealership_for_the_first/cbqu4fx) on buying a car is the sentence:

> if your salesman tries to use a 4 square ask for a breakdown of the price

I'm unable to find the meaning of "to use a 4 square" in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foursquare) or [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=four%20square).  Various meanings are listed, but none make sense in context.  What does *to use a 4 square* mean in the aforementioned sentence?

Answer (score 7):

This is not really general English, just vernacular from the world of car dealerships which are in the (often shady) business of selling vehicles.

In a nutshell, the four-square is a sheet of paper used by some dealers when negotiating the price of a car. It lists four numbers arranged in a square: the trade-in value of your previous car, the price of the car being purchased, the down payment, and the monthly payments. Used car dealers use techniques like [misdirection](http://youtu.be/HWuSTCj3Y4E) to make customers consent to a higher total price by playing with these four figures.

You can read more about this [here](http://consumerist.com/2007/03/30/dealerships-rip-you-off-with-the-four-square-heres-how-to-beat-it/), [here](http://www.mymoneyblog.com/confessions-of-a-car-salesman-beware-of-the-four-square.html), or [here](http://www.edmunds.com/car-loan/four-square-basics.html).

Incidentally, I found those websites by Googling `what is 4-square used cars`. (I had a feeling, since you were unsuccessful in your searches, that it was something strictly related to automotive sales.)